# cocos2d-x-3.0alpha1 touch events?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm just getting started with cocos2d-x and am using the 3.0 alpha 1 version. I have the following code below trying to setup to handle an onTouchBegan event, but I'm getting an error in Xcode saying "Incomplete type 'cocos2d::EventListenerTouch' named in nested name specifier.

```
auto _touchListener = EventListenerTouch::create(Touch::DispatchMode::ONE_BY_ONE);
_touchListener->setSwallowTouch(true);
_touchListener->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event){ this->touchMe(touch, event); return true;};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create()` instead.

But I don't know why can't use `EventListenerTouch`.